# LocalConnection: Simple example works in Flash 10 but not Flash9

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, localconnection

The following code, which is pretty straight out of any Adobe example works fine on Flash 10, but when run in Flash 9, the sending connections `onStatus` event receives 'error'.

The expected behavior in this example is that the `listeningConnection.ready` method is invoked on SWF1.

A demo of this can be seen on http://easyxdm.net/beta/tests/flash.html (single SWF with conditional logic).

**UPDATE**
The culprit was Flash's caching mechanism as we were using a single flash with conditional branching and not two individual swf-files.

Anyone know if there was a restriction lifted, or a bug fixed related to this in Flash 10?

**SWF1**

```
public static function main(swfRoot:MovieClip):Void 
{
    var channelName = "_channel";
    var listeningConnection:LocalConnection  = new LocalConnection();

    listeningConnection.ready = function() {
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "ready");
    };

    listeningConnection.allowDomain = function(domain) {
        return true;
    };

    if (listeningConnection.connect(channelName)) {
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log","listening on " + receivingChannelName);   
    } else {
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log","could not listen on " + receivingChannelName);    
    }
}
```

**SWF2**

```
public static function main(swfRoot:MovieClip):Void 
{
    var channelName = "_channel";
    var sendingConnection:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();

    sendingConnection.onStatus = function(infoObject:Object) {
        switch (infoObject.level) {
            case 'status' :
                ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "LocalConnection connected successfully.");
                break;
            case 'error' :
                ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "LocalConnection encountered an error.");
                break;
        }
    };

    if (sendingConnection.send(channelName, "ready")) {
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "called 'ready'");
    }else{
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "error calling 'ready'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this strange error occurred was that it was the same SWF-file references by the two object-tags. The code would branch differently based on provided variables, but due to the due to the same path being used for both, Flash9's caching mechanism kicked in and caused this to err.

So, the simple solution was to use `?host=true/false` behind the src in order to circumvent the caching.